# Regex HTAccess Not functioning

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have this rule in my .htaccess file. It correctly stops the rewrite for the "files" directory but none of the other directories. I expected this to not redirect the files, pdf, img, and account directories.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(files|pdf|img|account).*$ [NC]
```

I also tried it with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^(files|pdf|img|account)].*$ [NC]
```

This stops the redirecting for the all the requested directories but also for the mobile site so I think this just breaks the whole rule set I have.

My rule set is kind of long it so for redirecting from our main site to m.mainsite for mobile devices. If it'd be useful to see the whole set please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `REQUEST_URI` try `THE_REQUEST` variable as `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(files|pdf|img|account) [NC]
```

Comment: Yup, just swapping it to `the_request` has it functioning correctly. Thanks. Is there a way to output the different server variables for debugging in the future?

Comment: Yes in php code you can use: `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in PHP code to output various variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two condition statements instead of just the one.  One for the directory and then one for anything inside the directory such as a file or another directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(files|pdf|img|account)/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(files|pdf|img|account)/(.*)$ [NC]
```